# Serializing link to Django object with json in Google Map infowindow

Tags: django, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm serializing data from my Django model into json and placing that info in an infowindow in a Google Map. It works fine thus far. But I'd like to also include a link to each actual object so that a user could click a url that takes them to the full report. I'm not sure how to accomplish this using json as I'm still getting a handle on it.

Essentially using json to provide a link in the Google Map infowindow to the actual object, which in this case is a 'Story" model. I want a link to the actual story to appear in the Google Map info window.

This is my view:

```
def all_stories(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("django.contrib.auth.views.login")
    all_stories = Story.objects.select_related().order_by('-date')
    storyJson = []
    for story in all_stories:
        storyJson.append({
            "latitude": story.latitude,
            "longitude": story.longitude,
                "headline": story.title,
                "copy": story.copy,
                'author': story.author.username,
                'topic': story.topic
        })
    return render_to_response("report/storyline.html",
                                {'stories': all_stories,
                                "story_Json":json.dumps(storyJson)},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is the portion of the template relating to displaying the current information:

```
    function loadMarkers(stories){
    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];

        (function(story) {
            var pinColor = "69f2ff";
                var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|" + pinColor,
                    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, icon: pinImage});
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div >'+
                '<div >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+story.headline+'</h2>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<p>'+story.author+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.topic+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.copy+'</p>'+

                '</div>'+
                '</div>'

          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this);
          });
        })(story);
    }
}
```

Any insight on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the answer involves something you haven't yet posted, so I will make the assumption and you can extrapolate.

All you really need to do is use a [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) value for each story and include them in your json values. The [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) needs to point at the url that you point at the view for a single story. Lets assume your single story view looks like this:

```
url(r'^story/(\d+)/$', 'story.views.story_details', name="story-details")
```

Now as you build dict values for each story, include a [reversed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) url:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

host_url = "http://%s" % request.META['HTTP_HOST']

for story in all_stories:
    full_url = '%s%s' % (host_url, reverse('story-details', args=(story.id,)))
    storyJson.append({
        "latitude": story.latitude,
        "longitude": story.longitude,
            "headline": story.title,
            "copy": story.copy,
            'author': story.author.username,
        'topic': story.topic,
        'url': full_url
    })
```

This part is just an assumption, but I think your "info window" format might look like this:

```
content: '<div >'+
...
'<a href="'+story.url+'">View Story</a>'+
'</div>'+
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Just need to figure out how to put an href into the infowindow format. Many thanks! Curious: what exactly does the "reverse" accomplish?

Comment: reverse() will resolve the url name and arguments to the actual url that would call it. basically you are saying "given this view type with these args, where would the url be?". If you name your url patterns, you can use them later for this purpose.

Comment: I added a suggestion for the javascript template

Comment: Thanks, again. Got it all working. This is my first project and every bit of context helps me learn.

Comment: Hmm. Don't see your template suggestion. Was curious to see it.

Comment: Excellent. I did it this way and it worked but I prefer using Django tags so I'll try yours as well: '<p><a href='+story.url+'>Click to read story</a></p>'+

Comment: Ah yes I overlooked that you were referring to the story object as a javascript context. My example was a template tag. Glad you got it working!